# Using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers on .NET Framework 4.6 projects

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Visual Studio 2019 solution consisting of 50 .NET Framework 4.6.x projects, which are a mixture of:

1. Windows Forms applications
2. "Web site projects"
3. "Web application projects"
4. Class libraries

A customer is requiring us to use some form of static code analysis and they are accepting the free tools offered by Microsoft. Years ago, we used to use FxCop until Microsoft deprecated it and we removed it. Implementing FxCop was fairly simple - we enabled it in our project files and set up a code analysis rule set file that we linked into each project file. Pretty easy.

I see that Microsoft has yet another set of static code analysis tool - the flavor of today appears to be "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers". I've read through a lot of documentation and I can't find a clear guide to implement this new tool for apps targeting older .NET Frameworks - there is plenty of info on doing this on .NET 5, but we are nowhere near ready for such an undertaking.

Has anyone had any luck implementing this new static code analysis tool from Microsoft on a set of projects:

1. Targeting .NET Framework 4.6.x (or even .NET 4.x)
2. Using Visual Studio 2019 16.9
3. Enabling rules by category (our customer wants us to enable the "Security" rules)

If so, can you point me towards some documentation that covers the 3 aspects above?

Thanks!!

- Joe

Comment: Why does a customer even care about static code analysis?

Comment: Here is documentation for visual studio 2019 source code analysis: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/roslyn-analyzers-overview?view=vs-2019. You can find more information on same site by just changing the filters for what you're concerned with.

Comment: @Alejandro - the customer has compliance requirements that they impose on their vendors.

Comment: @ironman - that documentation "tree" seems focused on .NET 5. There are lots of statements surrounding .NET 5 that make it difficult to figure out what I need to do in .NET 4.x. For example, in this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/overview, they talk about the "rules are enabled, by default, in .NET 5.0", with no mention of .NET 4.x. The document talks about needing a "EnableNETAnalyzers" tag for < .NET 5 projects, but it doesn't really spell out how to pick and choose what rules are turned on.

Comment: @JoeC The article is for Visual Studio 2019. In the documentation it states that you don't have to move to .NET 5 yet "Install as a NuGet package: If you don't want to move to the .NET 5+ SDK or if you prefer a NuGet package-based model, the analyzers are also available in the Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers NuGet package on Visual Studio 2019."

Comment: @ironman - that is correct, but I don't see any documentation that tells you how to implement that package in .NET 4.x - aside from the "EnableNETAnalyzers" tag which must be manually added to the csproj file for any non-.NET 5 projects. That aside, I did a few hours of experimenting and it seems as though these analyzers still obey the "ruleset" files, but the documentation doesn't state that.

Comment: Also interested in this. It seems Microsoft have, yet again, shot themselves in the foot with all of this circular documentation that leads to nowhere but a bunch of deprecated packages which Visual Studio then complains about.

Comment: I take it back... these analyzers do not seem to respect the "ruleset" files. Why isn't this easier to set up? Why aren't there elements in the Visual Studio UI to control the behavior of these analyzers?

Comment: Ok, after about 6 hours of research between Microsoft documentation, blog posts and GitHub, I finally figured out how to do some of this. I was able to create a solution-level "editorconfig" file (why I had to learn yet another file format to do this is beyond me... but I digress) and I was able to control the inclusion/suppression by rule category using these two entries:

dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.category-security.severity = error
dotnet_analyzer_diagnostic.severity = suggestion

How do I make this work on a "web site project"? They have no project file for "EnableNETAnalyzers"